# How to explode a list into a Map in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Imagine you want to transform this:

```
val initialValues: List<Pair<String, String>>
```

where the first String represents a key, the second a value

into a map:

```
val finalMap: Map<String,String>
```

containing each pair item twice, the first with the original key, the second one with a sort of expanded key.

How would you do that? Currently I'm using a

```
val finalMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
```

that I use while I'm iterating over `initialValues`. But I really don't like it.

```
initialValues.forEach {
    val explodedPairs:List<Pair<String,String>>  = <do-something> 

    explodedPairs.forEach { finalMap.put(it.first, it.second) }
}
```

how would you do more assertively?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `associate` / `associateBy` like this -

```
val map1 = initialList.associate { it.first to it.second }
println(map1.toString()) //{1=x, 2=y}

val map2 = initialList.associateBy({it.first},{it.second})
println(map2.toString()) //{1=x, 2=y}
```

You can also use `toMap` and do this -

```
val map3 = initialList.toMap()
println(map3.toString()) //{1=x, 2=y}
```

where this is my initialList declaration -

```
val initialList = listOf(Pair(1, "x"), Pair(2, "y"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [associate](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html) and [associateby](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-by.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`mapOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html) like this:

```
val initialValues: List<Pair<String, String>> = listOf()
val final = mapOf(*initialValues.toTypedArray())
```

But @Supriya has the better answer using [`toMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html)